# Convergence is not uniform

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that $limf'_n(x)$ exits for each $x\in R$ and then trying to prove that this convergence is not uniform

$$f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$$

I calculated the derivative with respect to x and got the following

$$f'_n(x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+x^2}}$$

then taking the limit of this function I got the pointwise limit to be $|x|$. Therefore the pointwise limit is limit is $1$ if $x>0$, $0$ if $x = 0$ and $-1$ if $x < 0$.

Now I am trying to prove that this convergence is not uniform.

To do so I want to use the fact that

$$sup|f'n(x)-f(x)| >= b_n$$

where $limb_n \ne 0$

Do I need to prove for all 3 pointwise limits? and what can I choose by $b_n$ to be so I can show that this convergence is not uniform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x>0$, we have

$$\quad\sup|f'n(x)-f'(x)|$$
$$=\ \sup\left|\frac x{\sqrt{\frac1n+x^2}}-1\right| $$
$$\ \ \geq\ \left|\frac {\sqrt{\frac1n}}{\sqrt{\frac1n+\left(\sqrt{\frac1n}\right)^2}}-1\right|$$
$$=\ \left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac1n}}{\sqrt{\frac2n}}-1\right|\qquad\quad\ $$
$$\qquad\quad\ \ =\ 1-\frac{\sqrt2}2\ >\ 0\qquad\text{(as $n\rightarrow\infty)$}$$

Use the same trick when $x<0$

$$\quad\sup|f'n(x)-f'(x)|$$
$$=\ \sup\left|\frac x{\sqrt{\frac1n+x^2}}+1\right| $$
$$\ \ \geq\ \left|\frac {-\sqrt{\frac1n}}{\sqrt{\frac1n+\left(-\sqrt{\frac1n}\right)^2}}+1\right|$$
$$=\ \left|-\frac{\sqrt{\frac1n}}{\sqrt{\frac2n}}+1\right|\qquad\quad\ $$
$$\qquad\quad\ \ =\ 1-\frac{\sqrt2}2\ >\ 0\qquad\text{(as $n\rightarrow\infty)$}$$

Comment: but what about the other cases?

Comment: Okay, I will add other cases

Comment: so it would be +1 instead of -1 for x<0? and how about x=0?

Comment: what happens with x=0? thanks for your edit

Comment: @user19090 No worries :) The cases of $x>0$ and $x<0$ are enough to show the convergence is not uniform, so we do not need to consider $x=0$. Furthermore, we can no longer set the value of $x$ as we want when $x$ is fixed at 0, so there is nothing left to do when $x=0$

Comment: so because these  are >0 and they do not =0 then the convergence is not uniform?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to show a convergence is non-uniform

Comment: thanks for your help, it was very helpful

Comment: Oops, I should mention $n\rightarrow\infty$ when we calculate both supremums, sorry for that.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that

Comment: @user19090 Basically, $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly on $I$ means
$$
\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0\text{ as }n\to \infty.
$$So as you said, if this is greater than 0, then it is non-uniform convergence

Comment: okay and the answer you have provided remains the same?

Comment: Yes, the answer is the same but not as formal as this definition.

Comment: so then should I try and use that definition?

Comment: i thought that was the definition we were using here

Comment: Yes that was the definition we were using here, but I did not state it clearly in my previous answer, so I showed it again in the comments.

Comment: okay well thanks again

Comment: You are so welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Since each $f_n'$ is continuous, if the convergence of the sequence $(f_n')$ were uniform, the limit would be continuous ... And this is *not* the case.

Comment: how do I show that the limit is not continuous?

Comment: As you noticed in the OP, the limit of $(f_n')$ is the map $g:x\mapsto\cases{-1\quad\mathrm{if}\,x<0\cr0\quad\mathrm{if}\,x=0\cr1\quad\mathrm{if}\,x>0}$.

So $\lim_{0^-}g=-1\neq1=\lim_{0^+}g$